# XLib: клавиши GUI, NumLock, CapsLock, Mode и другие

Tags: c++, клавиатура, x11, xlib

Мне нужно поймать такие клавиши, как GUI, NumLock, CapsLock, Mode и другие. 
Вот, например, как я ловлю Control:

```
...
case XK_Control_L: return EGE_KEYMOD_LCTRL;
...
```

Но клавиши `XK_Gui_L` нет. И других. Где можно найти их имена?

Comment: Посмотрите keysymdef.h

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос решен.

Comment: @HermannZheboldov Пожалуйста, перенесите ваш комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуйста, посмотрите keysymdef.h
http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/keysymdef.h

```
#define XK_BackSpace                     0xff08  /* Back space, back char */
#define XK_Tab                           0xff09
#define XK_Linefeed                      0xff0a  /* Linefeed, LF */
#define XK_Clear                         0xff0b
#define XK_Return                        0xff0d  /* Return, enter */
#define XK_Pause                         0xff13  /* Pause, hold */
#define XK_Scroll_Lock                   0xff14
#define XK_Sys_Req                       0xff15
#define XK_Escape                        0xff1b
#define XK_Delete                        0xffff  /* Delete, rubout */
```

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на файл, что ли. С небольшой выдержкой, состоящей из кодов для указанных в вопросе клавиш.